# dialing iPhone on iOS9

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

There are many answers for this question, but on iOS 9 there are some problems. When I use this code:

```
NSString *phoneNumber = [@"telprompt://" stringByAppendingString:self.lblPhone.text];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];
```

I got this error:

> LaunchServices: ERROR: There is no registered handler for URL scheme (null)

Then I change the Info.plist with this:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>telprompt</string>
    <string>tel</string>
</array>
```

But nothing changed!

So I tried second code and this works:

```
NSString *numberString = @"004986632461";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"telprompt://%@",numberString]]];
```

But this one not:

```
NSString *numberString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [[_lblPhone text] floatValue]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"telprompt://%@",numberString]]];
```

It's dialing, but the number is wrong. Any idea?

Comment: Instead of using compound statements split them up using intermediate variables so you can debug easier and that will make it easier to understand the code and see problems. In this case with `NSURL *telURL = [NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber];` you would easily see that the URL and be able to focus on the solution.

Comment: Why are you attempting to treat a phone number as a `float` value? Phone numbers are strings, not numbers.

Comment: What is phoneNumber  & numberString, NSLog them all and add that yo y question

Comment: Note that the `tel` and related schemes do not include `//` (there is no `/` digit on phones). That probably isn't breaking you here because iOS likely is forgiving of misusing the scheme, but it's good to use it correctly to avoid surprises. Each scheme has its own rules. `//` is a part of the `http` scheme, not a generic part of URIs. http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3966.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second bit of code doesn't work because you are attempting to format the text as a floating point value.

This line:

```
NSString *numberString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [[_lblPhone text] floatValue]];
```

Will result in a value of `4986632704.000000` for the string `@"004986632461"`.

Skip the `float` part. Just do:

```
NSString *numberString = _lblPhone.text;
```

Don't ever try to treat a phone number as a numeric value. It's text and should only be treated (and stored) as text.

Comment: Thanks, but this version i also tried. Here is the same ErrorCode: LaunchServices: ERROR: There is no registered handler for URL scheme (null)

Comment: Silly question but are you testing on a real device? You can't test this on the simulator.

Comment: Yes, i know that there is a difference between the simulator and the iPhone. So i try only on real device! Thanks for question.

Comment: Is the call actually being made or do you just see the error?

Comment: There is no call on iPhone.

Comment: Yes, it's always the same: NSString *numberString = _lblPhone.text;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",numberString]]];

Comment: What exactly is the value of `numberString`? Make sure it has no spaces. Also try rebooting the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
NSString *phoneNumber = [@"tel://" stringByAppendingString:self.lblPhone.text];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];
```

Previously `telprompt` was used by most developers since it will return to app after the call while `tel` will return to home screen. But from iOS 8 onwards, `tel` will return to the app after call. So you can use that.

Comment: Thanks for answering immediately, but after compiling und run on iPhone i got this ErrorCode: LaunchServices: ERROR: There is no registered handler for URL scheme (null)

Answer (score -2):

I solved this problem myself. It's very easy. I must clean invisible spaces!

```
NSString *numberString = [_lblPhone.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

Comment: No, you didn't solve this yourself. You had lots of help including my answer and my comments where I told you make sure the string had no spaces.